# Using dialog from background crashes app

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bunch of AsyncTasks which fetch data.  They update the progress as they are executing by displaying dialog boxes.  Sometimes this causes the app to crash when the app is in the background (not visible).  My code called in below.  What checks can I do to keep the app from crashing without re-factoring the dialog box entirely?

These are declared in DownloadAsyncTask and passed in on constructor

```java
protected ProgressDialog mDialog;
protected String mDialogMessage = "Loading Data";
protected ProgressBar progBar;

doInBackground() {
    if ( mProgressBar != null && mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        mUIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } else if ( mDialog != null && !mDialog.isShowing() ) {
        mUIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDialog.setMessage(mDialogMessage);
                mDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then `onPostExecute()`:

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(DefaultHandler handler) {
    super.onPostExecute(handler);
    if ( progBar != null && progBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ) {
        progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if ( mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing() ) {
        try {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }   
    }   
}
```

UPDATED CRASH LOG:

> 12-20 15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@41a37908 is not valid; is your activity
>   running? 12-20 15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
>   12-20 15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   12-20 15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):   at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) 12-20 15:19:15.802:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9529):   at
>   com.*.DownloadAsyncTask$2.run(DownloadAsyncTask.java:119) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-20 15:19:15.802:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9529):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-20
>   15:19:15.802: E/AndroidRuntime(9529):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-20 15:19:15.802:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9529):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

Comment: Please post a stack trace showing the exception and its source, so that we can better advise you of what you are doing wrong.

Comment: It does not happen very often.  I did save the log file somewhere ...

Comment: Line 119 is:  @Override
      public void run() {
       mDialog.setMessage(mDialogMessage);
             mDialog.show();
      }

Comment: Line 119 is inside doInBackground()

Answer (score 1):

You are touching the UI from the background thread.  Android technically says "do not update", but it is best to read that as "do not interact with the UI on background threads".  Your `if` statement essentially says "if (...) is true about the UI, post this task to be executed on the UI thread *at some time in the future*".  By the time your `Runnable` executes on the UI thread, the UI's state may have changed.  It is probably better to encapsulate the entire logic and ship that to UI thread to be executed.  You could do that by combining the two `Runnable`s you have, and shipping in a single `post`, but `AsyncTask` was designed so you would not need to deal with handlers directly.  If you call `publishProgress()` in doInBackGround it will post a call on the UI thread to the `onProgressUpdate()` member.  Therefore, the easier thing to do is combine the code in your `Runnable`s and move to the `onProgressUpdate()` method.

Something like --

```
   void onProgressUpdate() {
            if (mProgressBar != null && mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (mDialog != null && !mDialog.isShowing()) {
                mDialog.setMessage(mDialogMessage);
                mDialog.show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok.  This looks like a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

you should check that activity is not finished.

use this:

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
    mDialog.show();
    }
```

check this page for more description:

http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads/

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUiThread(runnable) to avoid crash: this essentially runs the code segment in the run method on the UI thread. wrap all the UI operations you would want to perform in the run method as show below.

so the code would go something like:

yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // whatever UI operations..
                ..
                mDialog.setMessage(mDialogMessage);
                mDialog.show();
            }
```

});

Comment: can you connect that approach to an AsyncTask which is producing updates of status?

Comment: yes, we can! AsyncTask basically is a task that is carried in a bg thread. So inside onPostExecute, we can use this approach i thought!